# Change canonicalization algorithm with WCF service or in SoapUi

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soapui, ws-security

i'm trying to develop WCF service with WS-Security (Https and messages signed), basically - it's working and i can consume it with my .NET client app, but i need to be able to test this webservice with SoapUi. I can generate almost the same request like made by my .NET client app, but with only one difference - SoapUi use canonicalization xml-exc-c14n# like:

```
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
   <InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="wsse s" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
</ds:Transform>
```

and my .NET client like:

```
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
```

I've tried samples from
[Change canonicalization algorithm with WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30779840/change-canonicalization-algorithm-with-wcf) to change this,
but without success. I can't set defaultAlgorithmSuite variable with class derived from SecurityAlgorithmSuite because WCF throws ArgumentOutOfRangeException but only on runtime. 
Below's my configuration:

```
EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("dest_wcf_address"), EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity("cert"));
CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding();
AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement asec = (AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement)SecurityBindingElement.CreateMutualCertificateBindingElement(MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10);
asec.SetKeyDerivation(false);
asec.AllowInsecureTransport = true;
asec.IncludeTimestamp = true;
TextMessageEncodingBindingElement textMessageEncoding = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap11, Encoding.UTF8);
HttpsTransportBindingElement transport = new HttpsTransportBindingElement();
transport.RequireClientCertificate = false;

binding.Elements.Add(asec);
binding.Elements.Add(textMessageEncoding);
binding.Elements.Add(transport);

config.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceMetadataBehavior { HttpGetEnabled = true, HttpsGetEnabled = true });
config.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceDebugBehavior { IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true });
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
config.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "cert_cn"); 
config.Credentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(
StoreLocation.LocalMachine,
 StoreName.My,
 X509FindType.FindBySubjectName,
 "clienct_cert_cn");
config.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Authentication.
                        CertificateValidationMode =
                                X509CertificateValidationMode.Custom;
config.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Authentication.CustomCertificateValidator = new CustomX509CertificateValidator();
config.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
ServiceEndpoint endpoint = config.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), binding, "service_address");
endpoint.Address = address;
```

So how to change canonicalization algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found the way to change Canonicalization algorithm but the problem was different - SoapUI doesn't trim whitespaces while calculating signature hash using EXC-C14N. Pretty print in xml broke security. As solution we can set Strip Whitespaces property in SoapUI on Request level, or manually remove them from body element.